# Moving my custom farm solutions from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint 2013 error

Tags: 2013, deployment, iis, farm-solution, application-pool

So I followed the following guide. 
http://zimmergren.net/technical/upgrading-your-sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions-to-sharepoint-2013

Once I tried to deploy the solution from visual studio 2013 i got the following error:

Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here's what I've tried so far:
-Restarted computer
-Restarted vs 2012
-Reset IIS
-Reset IIS Application Pool

I've tried all of these and have had no luck! Someone please help me. Thank you!

Comment: you've been running all these in Administrator mode on a computer having SP2013 installed? Did you tried changing from Recycle app pool to None

Comment: how would you do that?

Comment: With the solution package selected check the properties window

Comment: can't see it, i only see name, active config, description, path, startup object

Answer (score 0):

Several days ago, Evgeniy wrote on [his blog (Russian language)](http://volfar.com/sharepoint-2013-error-occurred-in-deployment-step-recycle-iis-application-pool-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=sharepoint-2013-error-occurred-in-deployment-step-recycle-iis-application-pool-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object), that restart of the Windows Management Instrumentation service helped him (whereas restart of VS and iisreset didn't). Probably it helps you too.

Comment: hello thank you for your response. unfortunately it did not work.